# Using Android GeoFire with a FirebaseRecycler Adapter

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

Does any one know how to geoFire to populate FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.i.e using GeoFire to populate a Firebase RecyclerView

Comment: Hi LAN, Can you explain more what you want to do with geoFire ?

Comment: Hi Dhaval, I want to use keys within the target Location range obtained from the geoQery to populate a recyclerview using a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Can you help with an Example code?

Comment: As per my understaning you want to take geo location from geoFire and after getting location you want to fetch data from firebase other node or table and after then you want to display in FirebaseRecycler Adapter, Am I right ?

Comment: You are exactly right. That is what i want to do. Could you help??